# RABL: JSON objects without root key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I have this rabl template:

```
object @photo
attributes :id
child :comments do
  attributes :id, :body
end
```

Which gives me this JSON response:

```
{
  photo: {
    id: 1,
    comments: [
      { 
        comment: {
          id: 1,
          body: 'some comment'
        }
      },
      { 
        comment: {
          id: 2,
          body: 'another comment'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  comments: [
    { 
      id: 1,
      body: 'some comment'
    },
    { 
      id: 2,
      body: 'another comment'
    }
  ]
}
```

Why does rabl wrap each element in the array with an extra object called `comment`. In this way when I access the collection in javascript I have to write:

```
var comment = image.comments[0].comment
```

instead of:

```
var comment = image.comments[0]
```

I know that if I include `:comments` in the attributes list for the `@photo` object it works the way I want, but when I want another level of nested associations for each `comment` object, there isn't a way to handle that besides using `child`, but that gives me the JSON response that I don't want.

Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the whole thing -- can someone explain or help? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it!

Create a new file in `config/initializers/rabl_config.rb`:

```
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_json_root = false
  config.include_child_root = false

end
```

Comment: I had this same problem and found that I needed to add "config.include_child_root = false" in addition to include_json_root = false